# Div is not working on server side

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have this segment of code on server side of an ASP:Button, working perfectly.

```
div_message.InnerHtml = "Verificando Autentificaci&oacute;n...<img src='../../res/loader bar.gif' >"
```

But somehow, when i add more code, .innerhtml property is not showing .gif loader

```
Dim oCn As SqlConnection = Nothing

    Try 
        oCn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=" + _DataBaseName + ";Data Source=" + _SQL_Host + ";User Id=" + _SQL_Login + ";pwd=" + _SQL_Password)
        oCn.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        id_div_message.InnerHtml = "No ha podido establecerse la conexión con el servidor"
       Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnerHtml will set the entire contents of the div. You have to append rather than just set the value of the div.

```
id_div_message.InnerHtml += "No ha podido establecerse la conexión con el servidor"
```